# new Date().getUTCDate() not registering for an hour each day with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, datetime, mongoose

So I have this web app that people have started using and I want to track the total amount of time spent in the app by users. There's this function that makes a call every 5 minutes while a user is logged in that basically runs the following code to look up a Mongoose Schema (Statistics), and if it can't find one for that day, makes a new one:

```
let stats = await Statistics.findOne({
    'dateInfo.year': new Date().getUTCFullYear(),
    'dateInfo.month': new Date().getUTCMonth() + 1,
    'dateInfo.day': new Date().getUTCDate()
});
if (!stats) {
    stats = new Statistics();
};

stats.timeSpent += 5;

await stats.save();
```

The issue is that every day from 7:00PM to 8:00PM, I get many many new Statistics entries saved in my Mongo DB for the same Year/Month/Date combo.At first, I thought it might be something to do with Arizona and daylight savings time (since the only users that this happened for were from AZ the first day), but then more recently it was happening with users not in Arizona, so that idea's out the window.

Is there any reason why starting at 7:00PM Eastern US time a Mongoose object would save to the DB, but wouldn't be queried the next 5 minutes? It's VERY consistently only happening for exactly one hour between 7:00PM and 8:00PM ET.

The code for the Mongoose Schema looks like this:

```
const statsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    dateInfo: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
        default: {
            date: new Date(Date.now()),
            year: new Date().getUTCFullYear(),
            month: new Date().getUTCMonth() + 1,
            day: new Date().getUTCDate()
        },
    },
    timeSpent: {
        type: Number,
        required: false,
        default: 0
    }
});
```

EDIT: More information, I added a log to post out what the date, year, month, and day should be. In my index.js file, the log shows the correct date, UTC time. When I look at the statistic that is made and saved, however, it stores the date an hour off (which means if I create the Statistic from the mongoose model default, the date is saved as the previous day for one hour between 7:00PM and 8:00PM). It seems like Mongoose and Daylight Savings/Standard time aren't playing well. Is there any documentation to support this?

I'm trying to see what happens if I feed the

```
new Statistics()
```

with the specific object information instead of relying on the model defaults. e.g.,

```
new Statistics({
dateInfo:{
            date: new Date(Date.now()),
            year: new Date().getUTCFullYear(),
            month: new Date().getUTCMonth() + 1,
            day: new Date().getUTCDate()
        })};
```

Of course, this only happens between 7 and 8PM ET, so I'll let anyone following this know what happens tomorrow.
Any ideas or thoughts would be greatly appreciated

Comment: the above solution worked for me. No idea why - but making the new statistic with the info gave me the right info and resolved my problem - leaving the Mongoose schema default to populate the object did not work when just typing new Statistics()